# Mockito throwing 'Wanted but not invoked'

Tags: java, android, mockito, junit4

I have written the following Unit tests for my app. I have just started learning UnitTesting & Mockito so the exceptions/errors are kinda confusing. The following tests are throwing a weird exception.

***Mockito Error:***

```
Wanted but not invoked:
mComicListFragmentPresenter.createComicListFromServerResponse(
    [com.myapp.comic.models.serverResponse.Result@387a8303, com.myapp.comic.models.serverResponse.Result@28cda624, com.myapp.comic.models.serverResponse.Result@1500b2f3]
);
-> at com.myapp.comic.ComicListFragmentPresenterUnitTest.testForCheckingSuccessBehaviorUponFetchingComicsFromServer(ComicListFragmentPresenterUnitTest.java:47)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Wanted but not invoked:
mComicListFragmentPresenter.createComicListFromServerResponse(
    [com.myapp.comic.models.serverResponse.Result@387a8303, com.myapp.comic.models.serverResponse.Result@28cda624, com.myapp.comic.models.serverResponse.Result@1500b2f3]
);
-> at com.myapp.comic.ComicListFragmentPresenterUnitTest.testForCheckingSuccessBehaviorUponFetchingComicsFromServer(ComicListFragmentPresenterUnitTest.java:47)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

    at com.myapp.comic.ComicListFragmentPresenterUnitTest.testForCheckingSuccessBehaviorUponFetchingComicsFromServer(ComicListFragmentPresenterUnitTest.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

***UnitTest Code:***

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyUnitTest {

    @Mock
    ComicListFragment mComicListFragment;

    @Mock
    ComicListFragmentPresenter mComicListFragmentPresenter;

    List<Result> mResultList = Arrays.asList(new Result(), new Result(), new Result());
    @Test
    public void testForCheckingSuccessBehaviorUponFetchingComicsFromServer() {
       doNothing().when(mComicListFragment).onComicsFetchedSuccessfully(mResultList);
        Mockito.verify(mComicListFragmentPresenter, times(1)).createComicListFromServerResponse(mResultList);
        Mockito.verify(mComicListFragment, times(1)).onComicListCreationComplete();
    }
}
```

Comment: The error says that your test it is not passing because the methods in Mockito.verify are not being called. If you post the code in `ComicListFragment` and `ComicListFragmentPresenter` we can try to help you

Comment: Well what do you expect to be calling `createComicListFromServerResponse`? And where's the code you're trying to actually *test*? (At the moment, your test method looks like you're mocking out everything...)

Comment: put the code of your presenter here

Answer (score 1):

Sure!

You stabbed some invocation - described how it should behave in some situation. And immediately verifying that something was invoked. But you didn't run any method in the test. So that is why there zero interactions with your mocks.

You also don't have any real class instantiated in your test.